# Why is this version of Bayes theorem correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $A,B,C$ are events. My tutor wrote that Bayes theorem is

$$
P(A|B\cap C) = \frac{P(A\cap B|C)}{P(B|C)}
$$

I've just seen that
$$
P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)
$$
How does the former follow from the latter?

Comment: [This question was asked on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/258379/6633) just last week, and it might be worth your while to read the answers given there.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\Pr (A \vert E) \Pr (E) = \Pr (E \vert A) \Pr (A) = \Pr (A \cap E)$.

Let $E = B \cap C$, so that $$\Pr (A \vert B\cap C) \Pr (B\cap C) = \Pr (B\cap C \vert A) \Pr (A) = \Pr (A \cap B \cap C)$$

The left and right expressions give us that

$$ \Pr(A \vert B \cap C) = \frac{\Pr (A \cap B \cap C)}{ \Pr(B \cap C)} = \frac{\Pr(A\cap B \vert C) \Pr (C)}{\Pr (B \vert C) \Pr (C)} = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B \vert C)}{\Pr(B \vert C)} $$

where the second equality follows from the definition of conditional probability, similar to the second displayed equation above.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that for any events $X$ and $Y$, we have that:

> $$\Pr[X \mid Y] = \frac{\Pr[X \cap Y]}{\Pr[Y]}$$

Then observe that:
$$
\frac{\Pr[A \cap B \mid C]}{\Pr[B \mid C]}
= \frac{\dfrac{\Pr[A \cap B \cap C]}{\Pr[C]}}{\dfrac{\Pr[B \cap C]}{\Pr[C]}}
= \frac{\Pr[A \cap B \cap C]}{\Pr[B \cap C]}
= \Pr[A \mid B \cap C]
$$